# React.js ,screen Recorder and video Recorder

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to record screen both the application window and a PIP element simultaneously with react.js.

```jsx
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useMediaRecorder } from "react-media-recorder";

function App() {
  const [pipActive, setPipActive] = useState(false);
  const webcamRef = useRef(null);

  const {
    status: screenStatus,
    startRecording: startScreenRecording,
    stopRecording: stopScreenRecording,
    mediaBlobUrl: screenMediaBlobUrl,
  } = useMediaRecorder({
    video: true,
    screen: true,
  });

  const {
    status: webcamStatus,
    startRecording: startWebcamRecording,
    stopRecording: stopWebcamRecording,
    mediaBlobUrl: webcamMediaBlobUrl,
  } = useMediaRecorder({
    video: true,
    audio: true,
  });

  const togglePip = () => {
    setPipActive(!pipActive);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Screen Recorder with PiP</h1>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="screen-recorder">
          Screen Recording:
          {screenStatus === "recording" ? (
            <button onClick={stopScreenRecording}>Stop Recording</button>
          ) : (
            <button onClick={startScreenRecording}>Start Recording</button>
          )}
          {screenStatus === "stopped" && screenMediaBlobUrl && (
            <video src={screenMediaBlobUrl} controls />
          )}
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="webcam-recorder">
          Webcam Recording:
          {webcamStatus === "recording" ? (
            <button onClick={stopWebcamRecording}>Stop Recording</button>
          ) : (
            <button onClick={startWebcamRecording}>Start Recording</button>
          )}
          {webcamStatus === "stopped" && webcamMediaBlobUrl && (
            <video src={webcamMediaBlobUrl} controls />
          )}
        </label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="pip-toggle">
          PiP Mode:
          <input type="checkbox" checked={pipActive} onChange={togglePip} />
        </label>
      </div>
      {pipActive && (
        <div style={{ position: "fixed", bottom: 20, right: 20 }}>
          <video
            ref={webcamRef}
            autoPlay
            muted
            style={{ width: 200, height: 150 }}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```